# Navigator with variable not work

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

When i try to navigate to home.html like this is work:

```
 myNavigator.pushPage('home.html', { animation : 'slide' } )
```

But When i insert the page into the scope and try to navigate with the scope is not work.How can i do it? Thank in advance. I try this but not work:

```
 myNavigator.pushPage(+scope.page, { animation : 'slide' } )
```

i also try:

```
 myNavigator.pushPage('+scope.message', { animation : 'slide' } )
```

Answer (score 2):

check console.log(scope.page) / console.log($scope.page)
But i think `myNavigator.pushPage($scope.page, { animation : 'slide' } )`